# Kurento security concering ports

Tags: kurento

After successfully using Kurento in a development environment my team is looking to deploy an instance in a data center for production usage. However, data center security protocol dictates that the amount of ports opened in the firewall be held to a minimum. The Kurento documentation states that a wide range of ports has to be opened when using TURN, but does not go into detail on what ports are required, besides port `8888` for the WebSocket connection. Observing the ports opened by Kurento it seems that it opens random ports per connection. The server in question is not behind NAT, but only a firewall. Which ports need to be opened in the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

In normal scenario kurento media server will work if UDP ports 49152 - 65535 and TCP port 8888 is opened. If your server provider allow this ports range then you can configure firewall like this. 
if they do not allow then you should listen kurento on 443 or 80 port and block all other ports ,  then try to use tcp relayed turn server to establish webrtc connection.This approach will use more turn server resource because all connection relayed via turn.

Comment: I will attempt to test this approach. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Did you get it to work? Would you happen to have a sample docker-compose.yml?